# How to put standard value at top of dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net

My dropdown will be populated with data from an entity model as follow:

```
    HotelTestDatabaseEntities hotelData = new HotelTestDatabaseEntities();
    var afdelingQuery = from afd in hotelData.Afdelings
                        orderby afd.afdelingNaam
                        select afd;
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "afdelingID";
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "afdelingNaam";
    DropDownList1.DataSource = afdelingQuery;
    DataBind();
```

How is it possible to put a "Select Value..." item on top of the dropdown list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this code after binding is done for DropDownList1.

```
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("Please Select One","0"));
```

Answer (score 2):

In your aspx page

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select Value</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and in code behind

```
DropDownList1.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "afdelingID";
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "afdelingNaam";
DropDownList1.DataSource = afdelingQuery;
DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks, This one was helpful too :)

Answer (score 0):

This is What I thought of and this workde for me

```
     int i = 0;
     foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
       {
           if (i == 0)
           {
               comboBox1.SelectedText = dr[0].ToString();
           }
           else
           {

               comboBox1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
           }
           i++;

       }
```